# How can I open skype with an account logged from a html button?

Tags: html, skype

i want to do this, I know how to open skype using its special commands in html using calls, video calls and all of that stuff, for example:

```
<a href="skype:skype.test.user.1?call&video=true">Connect with user 1</a>
```

and to open skype i am just doing this:

```
<a href="skype:">Open Skype</a>
```

But What I want to do is to launch skype with an account logged automatically, without using the skype checkbox "start session automatically" cause this app I am making will be launched from any pc, I dont know maybe I can use two text inputs inside a form in order to get the skype name and the skype password from the user, and then i can send this info to skype launching the button, how would you do this?

Comment: So, you want to have the password and username as part your HTML code? I doubt this is allowed, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: No man, I want the user to text his username and password in the two html text inputs and then to send that info to skype using the button

Comment: I think i can do this using js, but i dont know how to put text in the skype boxes

Comment: You can't do this with javascript because javascript runs on the browser, not on the skype client.

Comment: Ok, then how Can i do this? or Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Microsoft's [documentation on Skype URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882(v=office.15).aspx) states the following:

> Currently supported Skype URIs include:
>
> - Switching focus to the Skype client.
> - Initiating audio calls to other Skype users, phones, or mobile devices—both one-to-one dialogs and
>     multiparty conferences.
> - Initiating video calls to another Skype user.
> - Sending instant messages to an individual or establishing a group multichat.

Specifically for the `skype:` URI:

> - If the Skype client is not running—starts the Skype client, and
>     switches focus to the Skype main window.
> - If the Skype client is
>     already running—switches focus to the Skype client.
> - If the Skype
>     client is already running and has the current focus—no effect; the
>     Skype client retains focus.
> - If the Skype URI starts the Skype client,
>     focus is set to the Skype client’s main window (auto-login is
>     enabled), or to its sign-in dialog box (auto-login is not enabled). If
>     the Skype client is already running, the focus is set to the main
>     Skype window, even if a Skype client dialog box, such as the
>     Tools−>Options dialog box, is open.

There are no options to pass a username or password, you have to enable auto-login or have Skype client already logged on.

Also, keep in mind that you have to enable the ability to receive calls from anyone in order for the button to have any (practical) effect.